# Origin CSRF check fails on page load

Tags: csrf, referer

I'm trying to build a generic filter for many applications where the developer would specify what origins they want to accept requests from and my filter would do an origin check to prevent CSRF. However on page load, there's no origin header or referrer sent and so the filter blocks the page load. I know I could just allow GET requests to go through the filter, but as I don't know what's behind the filter I don't have a guarantee that the app doesn't process state changing GET requests. Is there a better way to do this without putting much burden on the application developer?

Comment: What about specifying a path where the origin in header, e.g. `/api` ?

Comment: Yeah, that's an option. It just requires more dev effort